# Access value of an element in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to access an xml file with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<descriptions> 
  <image> 
    <name>1.jpg</name>  
    <text>Investor Return</text> 
  </image> 
</descriptions>
```

How do I retrieve the value of "text" for "name" = 1.jpg? I have tried to use `$desc = $xml->xpath('image[name="'.$file.'"]/text');`
but it gives an array with contains a single simplexmlelement (no value). Can someone suggest a solution?

Thanks

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `//image` instead of just `image` (although, your original XPath also worked for me, see the demo [here](https://eval.in/511499)):

```
$raw = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<descriptions> 
  <image> 
    <name>1.jpg</name>  
    <text>Investor Return</text> 
  </image> 
</descriptions>
XML;
$file = "1.jpg";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($raw);
$result = $xml->xpath('//image[name="'.$file.'"]/text');
echo $result[0];
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/511502)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
Investor Return
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. I actually have multiple images and hence possibly would have to loop through them.